# STM32L4S9 USB MSC Host. USB 3.0 memory sticks behave erratically

Tags: stm32, usb-host

I have a project that uses STM32L4S9Zi uC. The host (FS) is working fine with USB2.0 memory sticks but it is not working correctly with the 3.0 USB sticks.

3.0 memory sticks do not enumerate every time and if they enumerate reading from the device fails.

My question is: do you know if there are any differences between them (when 3.0 one is connected to the 2.0 FS port)?

I tried also STM32 demo app (using AzureRTOS [ThreadX]) and it behaves similarly (enumerates better but also fails to read from the disk)

Comment: Do yo know if these USB3 sticks work properly with any other USB2 host? If you have a PC with a port you know is only USB2, or can get a USB2 hub, then try on that and see how they behave.

Comment: Yes, they work fine on my PC computer

Comment: You don't give any details on your board or schematics. Maybe the problem is not in code. But we also can't see your code. Problem could be anywhere.

Comment: @Justme my question is if someone did it. And then if yes - if it was working fine

Comment: @Justme the host MSC code is about 10-15k lines. Complicated state machine + RTOS on higher level

Comment: Which is exactly why it is impossible to say what the problem might be in the code or schematics. A single unrelated task could hog the CPU and it does not respond within reasonable amount of time. Plus you don't even say which USB stack/framework you use, so that anyone could say if there are known issues with it. Please look at your question, does it describe your scenario with enough information? In general, all USB3 mass storage control devices should work on USB2 hosts. Does your design give enough power for the USB devices?

Comment: @Justme Yes it has separate power to feed USB devices connected. 500mA. I am not asking for the solution, only asking if someone has done it and had similar problems or it was working fine.

Comment: @Justme found the problem - silicon glitch. I have found the workaround as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution (or rather workaround)

Unfortunately, this silicon has a hardware bug and when the USB host interrupt is invoked the `GINTSTS` register is not available on the bus (ie if you read it, it gives erratic values). It has to be read at least 3 times to get the correct interrupt status. Barrier instructions do not help.

As the software could not read it properly, the interrupt pending flag was not cleared and the interrupt was invoked again.

BTW STM programmers noticed that something is wrong and added code which instantly returns from the handler if it was invoked for no reason (which is a clear indication of a hardware problem).

```
    /* Avoid spurious interrupt */
    if (__HAL_HCD_IS_INVALID_INTERRUPT(hhcd))
    {
        return;
    }
```

BTW those "spurious" interrupts are 12% to 15% of the total number of interrupts.